# keep gettin "AssertionError: arrays and names must have the same length" while trying to use panda cross tab

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, crosstab

here is my code

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=2 , random_state=0)
clf.fit(df_train[features_train] , df_train['steps_title'])
y = clf.predict(df_test[features_test])
x = df_test['steps_title']
print(y)
print(x)
pd.crosstab(x, y , rownames='actual step', colnames='predict step')
```

steps_title is a title that shows the job processing level for the applicants.
and the output of x and y are:

```
y = [3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 2
 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 3 2 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 3 3]

x:

0      3
1      3
2      3
3      3
4      2
      ..
103    2
104    2
105    3
106    2
107    3
```

They both have the same length, which is 180.

I also try converting x and y to list using `tolist()` function
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the usage of `rownames` and `colnames`:

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

> **rownames : sequence, default None**
>
> If passed, must match number of row arrays passed.
>
> **colnames : sequence, default None**
>
> If passed, must match number of column arrays passed.

It cannot be a scalar. See the examples from the documentation to get a right usage.

```
pd.crosstab(x, y , rownames=['actual step'], colnames=['predict step'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with brackets:

```
>>> pd.crosstab(x, y , rownames=['actual step'], colnames=['predict step'])
predict step   2   3
actual step         
2             32   0
3              0  76
>>>
```

Since it's in plural `rownames` and `colnames`, you need to add brackets.